# The omission of "Be"

Tags: word-choice

Is the second "is" optional in my sentence and if I use "the electrician" with a singular verb would the "is" be optional too?

"The house is in a mess because we have got the workmen in. The plumber 1.is putting in a new bath, the electricians are rewiring the system, and the carpenter 2.is building us some new bookshelves."

Comment: Why did you not propose "deleting" the verb ***are*** after ***the electricians***? It's exactly the same syntactic context in all three cases (singular/plural doesn't really make any difference). In principle any or all could be omitted, and there might be a *slight* stylistic argument saying that if you're only going to omit one or two, they should be either the last one or the last two. But I personally would prefer to keep all of them. Otherwise your text just looks like technical specification / timesheet recording / job control reporting.

Comment: I forgot to delete it, to be honest.